# Symfony: Submitted form get "must not be accessed before initialization" when data_class is specified

Tags: php, forms, symfony6

PHP 8.2-apache (Docker image)

Xdebug enabled
Symfony 6.4

**Quick summary**
I am creating form in Symfony 6.4 Framework and when it is submitted and request is handled, it tries to get value of unset entity, so it could set it. This problem is present only if data_class is specified, otherwise it gives an array without a problem. Mapping to the entity is a problem though.

**In more detail**

I am creating form in a standard Symfony way using a class

```
<?php 

...

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['username'], message: 'There is already an account with this username')]
class User extends AbstractADUCEntity implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    use UuidV7;
    use Username;
    use Password;
    use Vocative;
    use FullName;
    use Email;


    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function eraseCredentials(): void {}

    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return $this->getUsername();
    }
}
```

here my php traits are always the property, getter and setter, e.g. use Username gives the class this:

```
<?php 

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait Username
{
    #[ORM\Column(unique: true)]
    private string $username;

    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): static
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The form is then make as a class

```
<?php 

...

class SignUpType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Křestní jméno',
                    'data-field-name' => 'firstName',
                    'data-action' => 'keyup->sign-up#processControl'
                ],
            ])
            ...
        ;
    }
```

In this scenario everything works and the result after sending the form is [image: sent form]

My SecurityController is very straightforward at this time:

```
<?php
...

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('registrace', name: 'sign_up', methods: ['HEAD', 'GET', 'POST'])]
    public function signUp(Request $request): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SignUpType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        dump($form->getData());
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            die();
        }


        return $this->render('security/sign-up.html.twig', [
            'sign_up_form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Although if I add code into `SignUpType`

```
<?php 
...
     
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => User::class,
    ]);
}
```

[image: sent form with data_class]

This error is present for all properties of the `User` entity.

I have tried to downgrade Symfony version, since I am using version 6.4 in development, but the problem also prevailed on stable version 6.3.

Using xdebug I managed to find the path how the getter is called.
[image: The Xdebug trace]

I believe the problem starts within the setValue that tries to getValue before setting the object. [image]

One obvious way would be to set default values of all properties to empty strings `''`, but I do not like this solution since the object is really not initialized, thus I believe it should not have values that are not default.

I also tried to get rid of the traits and do this on a different entity with only one column, made by symfony maker. The story is the same, so it is not caused by the trait system I am using for doctrine entities.

And here I got stacked, not sure how to proceed from here.

**One interesting behavior**

While making the POST request with specified `data_class`, I run the xdebug and I found that the method handleRequest is going smoothly without a problem. But when I do not put breakpoint in the `handleRequest` method, but rather into the getter of username, we can see that it is going from `handleRequest` further. It seems to me like it would go two different paths, one when I see the xdebug in the process, and one when I put the breakpoint to the end in the getter. I am not able to explain this.

Edit: If I scroll few kilometers down below those errors, there is actually my dump with good entity. Therefore something else must be going on than creation of this entity.
[image]

Also if I run it without `dd`, it will fall on error "headers are already been sent". But I am not using any dump anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, so I want everyone to know, if headed the same way. The reason was xdebug settings that I would not image it could be.

My configuration file is

```
zend_extension=xdebug

error_reporting=E_NONE
display_errors=off

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
;xdebug.show_error_trace=1
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.log_level=0
```

The commented line `xebug.show_error_trace=1` caused this. I do not know why, but commenting it is the solution. Xdebug still works and now even the Symfony is acting like it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized a `User` object. Look closely at the [example in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms). Start by creating a `new User()` and pass it to the `createForm` method.

```php
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('registrace', name: 'sign_up', methods: ['HEAD', 'GET', 'POST'])]
    public function signUp(Request $request): Response
    {
        $newUser = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(SignUpType::class, $newUser);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // ToDo: persist the $newUser
            dump($newUser->getUsername());

            // $form->getData() holds the submitted values
            // but, the original `$task` variable has also been updated
            $newUser = $form->getData();
            dump($newUser->getUsername());

            die();

            // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
        }


        return $this->render('security/sign-up.html.twig', [
            'sign_up_form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no difference when I do it. As I understand Symfony Forms, this empty object is there if we want to specified some of its properties by hand without using the form on the webpage. The Mapper is creating the new object instance every time when it is not given explicitly. But I have tried, the error is still the same. I also edited my observations in the problem above. Now I know the entity is created well, but something else must be going on that I can't see :(